# I'm sending push notification when user registered, its only sending the notification to registered user, can I change that to everyone use the app?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

> Below code is my firebase function index.js file

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("Notifications/{userId}")
    .onWrite(event => {
        var request = event.data.val();
        var payload = {
            data: {
                title: "Welcome to ChitChat Group",
                message: "You may have new messages"
            }
        };

        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(request.token, payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message: ", response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
            })    
    });
```

> below code contains where i crate token when user get registered

```
String uid = (String) firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications/"+uid);
                 reference.child("token").setValue(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make all your users subscribe to one big topic like `registration` on `newMembers` then send notification to the topic :

```
var message = { 
 to: '/topics/newMembers',  
 notification: {
     title: 'title', 
     body: 'body' 
 },
};
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that step by step im new to these notification thing